# Animation not present in my html/css project with animated.css

Tags: html, css, animation

Hi to everybody friends... I have been started the css programming a few days ago and I have found on internet this website --> https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and with the help of some videos I have tried to use the animation offered in the website in my application, without results. Can someone help me to integrate the code in the website with my code? I would animate the div class="layout_generale".

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_registration.css">

<TITLE>Registrati</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM action="/Esercizio_14.3tomcat/registration" method="POST">
    <div class="layout_generale">
        <p>
            <BR> Nome <INPUT type="text" name="firstname" value=""><BR>
            <BR> Cognome <INPUT type="text" name="lastname" value=""><BR>
            <BR> <BR> 
            <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">
            Maschio<BR> 
            <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">
            Femmina<BR> <BR> 
            Email <INPUT type="email" name="email" value=""> <BR> <BR> 
            Username <INPUT type="text" name="username" value=""> <BR> <BR> 
            Password <INPUT type="password" name="password" value=""><BR> <BR>
            <BR> 
            <INPUT type="submit" value="Invio"> 
            <INPUT type="reset" value="Cancella">
        </p>
    </div>
</FORM>
```

and this is the css file:

```
.layout_generale {
    background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.8);
    border-radius: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    border: 5px solid lightgrey;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px; 
}

body{
    background-image: url('ft-bk.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    font-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetia, sans-serif; 
}

input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetia, sans-serif; 
}


input[type=text]:focus, 
    input[type=email]:focus,     
    input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: lightblue;
}


input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    background-color: #203231;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And I have the code downloaded from the website in another `CSS` file... Any helps? Obviously other ways to animate things are welcome.

Comment: You need to include the `animate.css` file in your web page....with that in place, you just need to change your `<div class="layout_generale">` to `<div class="layout_generale animated infinite bounce">`...if you want to animate just once, just remove the `infinite` class...and you can replace the `bounce` class with the animation of your choice...check the docs https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link the animate stylesheet in your HTML head like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
```

and then add the specific classes to your HTML element like:

```
<div class="layout_generale animated infinite bounce">Example</div>
```

The documentation explains it really well: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must include Animate.css in yout index.html

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>
```

So you shoud add class to your div. There are some method available in the documentation: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

My opinion is to use javascript (jQuery). (Replace 'yourAnimationName' with once animate.css animation)

```
$('.layout_generale').addClass('animated yourAnimationName');
```